# Cant seem to get value of input text fields value into hidden form fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, hidden-field

So I have a fiddle of the code:
http://codepen.io/databaseindays/pen/JGdgq

The idea is that the user can find their coordinates and then submit them via POST variables in hidden fields in the form.

Im using JQuery to simply read the lat and lang fields value into the hidden fields. But the POST variables are always empty. The values are not being copied.

One theory is that I have the hidden fields inside a FORM, while the inputs im trying to copy are not. So first question is, is that a scope issue? If so, should I omit the Form and submit another way, if that will give me access to the values?

Thanks

Norman

Comment: Would you mind editing the pen to pull the CSS and JS out into their own separate panes? It's a bit difficult to try to read them as part of the HTML document.

Comment: Michael, I found out the issue. I commented in the selected answer. Thanks anyway sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you're probably going to kick yourself when you see this. I know it took me a few minutes before I noticed.

It looks as if you're trying to copy the value in the jQuery block at the bottom of the page. However, that bit of code is only running when the document is ready, and NOT when the geocoding operation takes place.

Comment: Of course that makes perfect sense. JQuery is something I have not become very good at, also Javascript. Im a script copy and paster. I thought once you have document.ready, you can do all kids of javascripts stuff, like it was permanently listening. Thanks for pointing that out. What I got to work was: I added an On Submit to the form that calles a function, and in THAT function I ran manual Javascript to assign value of the other input field and it worked! Im still giving you the credit for the answer as you took the time and was first. Blessings.